# Upgrading Grafana from 8.2 to 8.3 causes loss of all alerts

Tags: json, devops, monitoring, upgrade, grafana

I'm upgrading Grafana (from 8.2.7 to 8.3.5) and all my alerts are gone. I have configured my dashboard in 8.2.7 as JSON and also added alerts in the same JSON file. I can see that when I export the dashboard it is the same JSON that I configured as input. However, in 8.3 onwards, when I create a dashboard and add an alert to it (from within the panel menu) and export it as JSON, the alert is not part of the same JSON anymore (but properly registered with Grafana as I can see it in the Alert Manager GUI).

I have read a lot (release notes, Google, posts in the Grafana community) and I think I oversee something here. Can someone point me in the right direction or did you solve a similar issue with Grafana already? Possibly I'm not the only one and maybe this post helps out others, too.

What I tried: see above.
What I expected: that Grafana 8.3 would register the dashboards with alerts, however, only the dashboard without alerts is created in Grafana (using JSON to describe the dashboard, panels and associated alerts). No obvious error message visible in the Alert Manager GUI.

Best Regards and thanks in advance